# Django test -- Model object created but cannot be found

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

I'm calling a Model which is called `People` and do

```
People.objects.create(first='foo', last='bar', bio='test')
```

This Model uses `db_table='"people"."background"'`

When I run the test, doing `People.objects.first()` finds something, but doing raw query like `SELECT * from people.background` gives me nothing. Why is that?

Comment: Tests run on a different database, typically with a `test_` prefix iirc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm aware of that. The table `people.background` is correctly created, and checking the description of the Model does show that db_table should be `people.background`. It should be connecting to the right database as far as I believe, but I cannot locate the created data......

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Django doesn't officially support schema.

I have come up with a workaround which connects to the db and makes a raw query directly. Essentially,

```
with connection().cursor as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO bleh bleh bleh""")  # assuming there's autocommit
```

EDIT:

Django's response: Django doesn't officially support schemas. See #6148 for that. As far as I know, the . syntax only works on Oracle.